# If a sequence is in $\ell_p$, then it's also in $\ell_{p'}$ for all $p'\ge p$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I need to prove something that feels rather intuitive but I'm not sure if my reasoning is sufficient.

> Prompt: suppose $x \in \ell_p$ for some $p \in [1,\infty)$. Show that $x \in \ell_{p'}$ for all $p' \geq p$

This is pretty intuitive because I know that larger $p$-norms get smaller. This made me think that it was a good idea to take the derivative of a p-norm, but he derivative contains the definition of a $p$-norm multiplied by more terms...

$$
\begin{align*}
\cfrac{d}{dp}\|x\|_p &= \cfrac{d}{dp}(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\cdots)^{1/p} \\
                     &= \frac{d}{dp}
e^{\ln(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\cdots)\cdot 1/p}\\
                     &= e^{\ln(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\cdots)\cdot 1/p} \cdot \frac{d}{dp} \ln(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\cdots){1/p}
\end{align*}
$$

and I eventually ended up with

$$
\begin{align*}
   (|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\cdots)^{1/p}\cdot \left(\cfrac{\ln(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\cdots)}{p^2} \right)
+ \cfrac{1}{p}\cdot \frac{\ln(|x_1|)\cdot|x_1|^p+ \ln(|x_2|)\cdot|x_2|^p+ \cdots}{|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\cdots}
\end{align*}
$$

Which I'm not finding super helpful.

Guidance on how to show the prompt would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \in \ell^p$, then $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p<+\infty.$$ In particular,
$$\lim_{n}|x_n|=0.$$

The last equality implies that there is a $n_0$ such that $|x_n| \le 1$ for every $n\ge n_0$.

Therefore, for every $n \ge n_0$ and $p'>p$, $|x_n|^{p'} < |x_n|^p.$ Then, by the comparison test:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^{p'}<+\infty$$

and $x \in \ell^{p'}$.

Comment: it seems like we have to assume that sequence is in a particular order. Is that something that's inescapable?

Comment: This is not necessary. Since the series $\sum |x_n|^p$ is absolutely convergent, any reordering of the terms will result in the same sum.